# Why is the string "IDK"not being detected by the .indexOf() method and isn't being output?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TextMsgDecoder {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      String message;
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Enter text:");
      message = keyboard.nextLine();

      System.out.println("You entered: " + message);


     if (message.indexOf("IDK") > 0) {
        System.out.println("IDK: I don't know");
      }
      if (message.indexOf("BFF") > 0) {
        System.out.println("BFF: best friend forever");
      }
     if (message.indexOf("JK") > 0) {
        System.out.println("JK: just kidding");
      }
     if (message.indexOf("TMI") > 0) {
        System.out.println("TMI: too much information");
      }
     if (message.indexOf("TTYL") > 0) {
        System.out.println("TTYL: talk to you later");
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: What input are you giving it? And have you tried `>=` instead of `>`? (The former will match at the start of the input line; the latter will match from the second character)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (message.indexOf("IDK") > 0) {
  System.out.println("IDK: I don't know");
}
```

This will only detect `IDK` in a string which doesn't start with `IDK`, e.g. `_IDK` will be detected (since `"_IDK".indexOf("IDK") == 1`), but not `IDK_` (since `"IDK_".indexOf("IDK") == 0`).

If you want to detect `IDK` anywhere including the start of the string, use either:

```
if (message.indexOf("IDK") >= 0) {
```

or, more idiomatically:

```
if (message.contains("IDK")) {
```

Answer (score 0):

youcomparing the input string, where your typing "IDK" to the INDEXVALUE of IDK. its turning your string into an int. so there is no match

try this instead:

```
 if (Objects.equals(message, "IDK")) {
        System.out.println("IDK: I don't know");
      }
```

what your doing is getting the index of "IDK" which may be zero, but it wont be greater than 0, so your if never fires

Comment: Never compare strings with `==` ([How do I compare Strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java?s=1|589.2131))

Comment: Syntax Error... not a typo. i caught this question in triage, and missed the java tag. its fixed now.